# Gmail like alert box (for infomation or error display) throught jQuery in ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, messagebox

I am looking for some sample code/control which gives me the feel of gmail like message box through jQuery in ASP.NET.

Answer (score 13):

I think what your looking for is [jQuery BlockUI](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/).

Have a look at the [demo's](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#demos).

Using css you can match the styles of gmail.

Comment: if you just want to show messages, using http://stanlemon.net/pages/jgrowl is more straightforward.

Answer (score 5):

You can use plugins, but you can also have a fixed DIV sitting at the top of your page and fade it in/out. Let's see an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>jQuery</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('input').click(function() {
                    $('#notification').fadeIn('slow');
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body style="height: 1000px;">
        <div id="notification" style="position: fixed; top: 0px; margin-left: 50%; background-color: yellow; font-weight: bold; display: none;">Sending...</div>
        <input type="button" value="Gmail notification!" />
    </body>
</html>
```

You have to work out how to hide it (a callback after the operation completes, etc.), style it and so on. That's just an example.